# Counting hours between two columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following list:

```
ID  In                        Out 
A   23.03.2018  08:16:14      23.03.2018  13:56:03
B   23.03.2018  11:16:14      23.03.2018  13:56:03
```

I have to create something like this:

```
ID  In                         
A   23.03.2018  09:00:00      
A   23.03.2018  10:00:00
A   23.03.2018  11:00:00      
A   23.03.2018  12:00:00   
B   23.03.2018  12:00:00
```

The columns "In" and "Out" contain each a date and a hour. What I need to do is to look at the hour from "In" and "Out" and count the hours between them. Each counted hour must be save in a line, like in the second table. It can be another table Result for example. If for example the In starts at 10:01:00, I will start to count from 11. Any idea how I can do this? I tried with a pivot table, but I do not think that is possible to count in this way. Thanks!

Comment: if you have a date & time value in cell A1 the following will give you the number of hrs elapsed in that datetime (in that day) as a decimal rounded to 2 decimals   =ROUND(24*(A1-INT(A1)),2)   which might help get you going. You could also use roundup or rounddown functions too and reducing 2 to 0 rounds to the hour

Comment: In your example `A` comes in at `08:16` and leaves at `13:56`. In your summary table for `A` you have four entries but should it not be five i.e. 9, 10, 11, 12, 13? You are rounding up the `in` time. How are you treating the `out` time?

Comment: Actually only four (9,10,11,12) because only "full hours" must be count. 13:56:03 means "stop at 13".

Comment: Is it possible for person 'C' to work for less than one full hour? If so, what should happen in this case?

Comment: @TomSharpe If a person works less then one full hour the time will not be counted, or it will be 0 in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub TimeSheet()
    Dim timeEntries As Range, entry As Range, startTime As Integer, endTime As Integer, hr As Integer, lastRow As Integer

    Set timeEntries = Worksheets("Input").Range("A2:A3")

    For Each entry In timeEntries
        startTime = GetHour(entry.Offset(0, 1), "IN")
        endTime = GetHour(entry.Offset(0, 2), "OUT")

        For hr = startTime To endTime

            With Worksheets("Output")
                lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Range("A" & lastRow) = entry
                .Range("B" & lastRow) = DateValue(entry.Offset(0, 1)) & " " & TimeSerial(hr, 0, 0)
            End With

        Next hr
    Next entry

End Sub

Function GetHour(t As Date, stamp As String) As Date
    Dim result As Date

    If stamp = "IN" Then
        If Minute(t) = 0 Then
            result = Hour(t)
        Else
            result = Hour(DateAdd("h", 1, t))
        End If
    Else
        If Minute(t) = 0 Then
            result = Hour(t)
        Else
            result = Hour(DateAdd("h", -1, t))
        End If

    End If

    GetHour = result
End Function
```

**Notes**

1. Worksheet `Input` has your `In` and `Out` data starting `A2` (first row as header)
2. Worksheet `Output` has your summary table starting at `A2` (first row as header)
3. The `GetHour()` function gets the start and end hour based on your logic

Comment: It works! Thanks! Howerver, there is a small problem. If in is "26.11.2018  09:36:00" and out "26.11.2018  09:36:19" the function will stop. In this case it should be 0 or go further without counting them.

Comment: Do you mean it should not count that whatsover i.e. not appear in the summary table?

Comment: O yes, sorry, was my mistake. Only if the difference is less then 1 hour and is the last line it will stop, but is fine. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! If I would also like to work with minutes (e.g. 09:01:00,09:02:00,09:03:00) what I need to change in the function? Thx

Comment: Use **second()** in the function. It’s same overall pattern.

Comment: Something like this second(t) insted minute(t)? and here   result = Hour(DateAdd("h", 1, t))?

Comment: Yes second(t). You’ll need Minute(DateAdd(“m”, 1, t). As I say if you follow same logic you can expand the code to round up / down to nearer minute.